# Nailing the frame into the cement floor

Tags: framing, nailing

I am trying to nail an inner frame into the cement floor.

what i did is hammering the nail.

it went all the way through the wood, but when it reached the cement the nail bent.

so how to fix the frame into the cement floor?

Answer (score 2):

you can use masonry nails or TapCon screws.  [Tap con](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Tapcon-10-Pack-3-in-x-3-8-in-Concrete-Anchors/4686253?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-hdw-_-ggl-_-LIA_HDW_126_Fastening-_-4686253-_-local-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=Cj0KCQiAwJWdBhCYARIsAJc4idBAIo4UCiUX-FxX_9GhH1FaUMhLdAhSrJhtANOCemc41IqlClX07FUaAifJEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Masonry nails are for uncured concrete. The tapcons need pilot holes drilled, but the drill bit often comes with the screws.

Comment: Or ramset nails. Or construction adhesive.

Comment: Ramset nails can be driven with a hammer, if you're careful. but yeah, they work better with the proper gun.